# Чтение определенных строк в Python

Tags: python, readline

Мне нужно  в файле x считать 5-9 строку, как это сделать?

Comment: Сперва прочитать 4-8 строк, и дальше будет 5-9 строка

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rows = file.readlines()[5:10]
```

Если файл небольшой, то можно и так

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("something.txt") as infile:
    for __ in "1234":
        next(infile)
    for __ in "56789":
        print(next(infile))
```

---

*Объяснение:*

1. `infile` - это *итератор*, потому  к нему возможно применить стандартную функцию `next()` для выдачи следующей строки файла.
2. Для цикла `for` я вместо традиционного `range(4)` использовал *строку длины 4.*
   Здесь это более наглядно, т.к. в ней номера пропущенных строк (`1234`).
3. Переменная цикла здесь *фактически не нужна*, но *синтаксически* она нужна — потому я (традиционно) применил для неё странное имя `__`.